# Access recordId in LWC child component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-dev-server, lwc-playground

Can I access the recordId directly in a LWC child component instead of passing it from parent component?

I put @api recordId in child component but im getting undefined.

Comment: no, you can't. you have to pass it from the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Child components must receive their recordId from the parent. Only top-level components get the recordId from a Record Page view.